# College student interested in starting a stock portfolio, how much should I invest?

Tags: stocks, savings, investing

I have about 6k in my bank account, Ill be graduating next year with about 20k in loans. I want to start investing now though, how much of my savings do you think I should invest in a stock portfolio.

Comment: Welcome to money.SE .  Too little detail here. What is the loan rate and monthly payment? What kind of job will you get? How does that job's income compare to cost of living in the area you'll be? Once we know this, some good answers will follow. (Also pls add a country tag.)

Answer (score 0):

You should invest a trivial (<500$USD) amount of money in a stock portfolio. If you aren't able to make more on the market than the interest rates of your loans, you are losing money. [This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-smart-is-it-to-really-be-100-debt-free) has discussed this topic as well.